# Rails nesting scope block in resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm trying to create a path like `product/:id/monthly/revenue/` and `product/:id/monthly/items_sold` and the equivalent named routes `product_monthly_revenue` and `product_monthly_items_sold`, and these routes would simply show the charts. I tried

```
resources :products do
    scope 'monthly' do
        match 'revenue', to: "charts#monthly_revenue", via: 'get'
        match 'items_sold', to: "charts#monthly_items_sold", via: 'get'
    end
end
```

But this gives me the routes:

```
product_revenue    GET    /monthly/products/:product_id/revenue(.:format)    charts#monthly_revenue
product_items_sold GET    /monthly/products/:product_id/items_sold(.:format) charts#monthly_items_sold
```

where `monthly` gets appended in front instead, and the route naming is off. I know I could just do:

```
resources :products do
    match 'monthly/revenue', to: "charts#monthly_revenue", via: 'get', as: :monthly_revenue
    match 'monthly/items_sold', to: "charts#monthly_items_sold", via: 'get', as: :monthly_items_sold
end
```

but that isn't DRY, and it gets crazy when I try to add more categories like yearly. Using a namespace would force me to create a new controller for each namespace, when I want to consolidate all the charts into a single controller.

So I guess the summarised question would be: is it possible to namespace routes without namspacing controllers? Or is it possible to consolidate the creation of categories of named routes?

**Edit**: Using

```
resources :products do
  scope "monthly", as: :monthly, path: "monthly" do
    match 'revenue', to: "charts#monthly_revenue", via: 'get'
    match 'items_sold', to: "charts#monthly_items_sold", via: 'get'
  end
end
```

would give me the routes

```
   monthly_product_revenue GET    /monthly/products/:product_id/revenue(.:format)    charts#monthly_revenue
monthly_product_items_sold GET    /monthly/products/:product_id/items_sold(.:format) charts#monthly_items_sold
```

which similar to the first block, is unexpected because I expect that if a scope is nested in a resources block, only the routes in the scope block would affected by the the scope, not the resources block.

**Edit 2**: Forgot to include this information earlier, but I'm on Rails 4.0.0, with Ruby 2.0.0-p247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I might approach:

```
periods = %w(monthly yearly)
period_sections = %w(revenue items_sold)

resources :products do
  periods.each do |period|
    period_sections.each do |section|
      get "#{period}/#{section}", to: "charts##{period}_#{section}", as: "#{period}_#{section}"
    end
  end
end
```

It is also possible to use named routes and pass the values to your controller method via params (be sure to properly validate before using):

```
resources :products do
  get ":period/:section", to: "charts#generate_report", as: :report
end

# report_path(period: 'monthly', section: 'revenue')
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a nice way to programmatically create the routes. I do forget sometimes that Rails is still Ruby and forget solutions like this.

It is still strange though that a `scope` in a `resources` block affects the resources block. Is that a bug?

Comment: @tempestfire2002 does well to never forget that Rails is Ruby :) I don't think `scope` is meant to be nested within a `resource` block. I've seen no examples of this. See here for reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-scope. I do agree, though, I wouldn't have expected the output you received.

Answer (score 14):

The real solution is to use `nested`:

```
resources :products do
  nested do
    scope 'monthly', as: :monthly do
      get 'revenue', to: 'charts#monthly_revenue'
      get 'items_sold', to: 'charts#monthly_items_sold'
    end
  end
end
```

Ref: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12626

Comment: Instead of `nested do ... end` use `member on ... end`. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes